# Convert text file (with html elements) into DOM using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, dom, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to convert the text file into DOM using BeautifulSoup ??

I have a text file which contains the Facebook html elements copied in it. I want to scrap FB data using the HTML elements but need to convert the text file into a DOM and pass the DOM to a function

```
Text=open(".txt").read()
bookDOM = BeautifulSoup(Text)
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but the code you have there will work fine. BeautifulSoup doesn't care if you file has txt or html extension, as long as data inside of the file could be parsed.

Comment: I did try it ...but when i print bookDOM it did not print anything

Comment: Yup. It parsed the html content. Thanks